# Open UFW port to specific IP with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ufw

I ran the following task copied right from the Ansible 2.9 [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ufw_module.html):

```
- name: Allow all access from RFC1918 networks to this host
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    src: '{{ item }}'
  loop:
    - 10.0.0.0/8
    - 172.16.0.0/12
    - 192.168.0.0/16
```

Of course, with my own IPs.

The problem is that although it loops through the IPs as the output below shows, the UFW rule keep open to Anywhere.

```
TASK [Allow 5431] ***********************************************************************************************
changed: [database3] => (item=my_ip1)
changed: [database1] => (item=my_ip2)
changed: [database2] => (item=my_ip3)
ok: [database3] => (item=my_ip1)
ok: [database1] => (item=my_ip2)
ok: [database2] => (item=my_ip3)
```

I've tried successfully deleting the allow rule and then running again the one with the loop like this, but does not work:

```
tasks:
    - name: Allow 5431
      ufw:
        rule: allow
        port: "5431"
        delete: yes
```

**The question is: how to use ufw module to limit a port's IP access?**

***UPDATE***

I am looping through a series of IPs that look like this:

```
  loop:
    - 10.0.0.0/0
    - 172.16.0.0/0
    - 192.168.0.0/0
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/7931d4445fe134f3ce1bdfc7362f8f7e)

Comment: I can see. I'll try today following your code and see how it goes. I'll keep you informed here. Thanks!

Comment: The problem goes on. My ```ansible --version``` is ```ansible 2.9.17```

Answer (score 0):

By going directly to the server and running the UFW command, I got

```
WARN: Rule changed after normalization
Rule added
```

UFW was changing my IPs because they all ended with xxx.xx.xxx.xxx **/0**

By removing the sub mask indicator, it all worked properly.

The problem is that the [submask binary AND operation](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation?newreg=c4b960263a54465b918c1d6a0519eb00) set to /0 transforms all the binaries to False or 0, so the *normalization* in this case turns any IP to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Why were you utilizing /0? That literally means everything. If you intend to specify a singular address, try using /32 at the end, as that signifies a single IP. [Here's a handy cheat sheet for CIDR notation reference.](https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/IPv4CIDRChart_2015.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the Cheat Sheet. The submask binary sometimes os confusing. But now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure to use the correct CIDR notation for your subnets (subnet masks). As per RFC1918 section 3, the correct subnets to cover these address spaces are:

- 10.0.0.0/8
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.168.0.0/16

Use those and your UFW rule will be in-scope for all of the private address space.

Source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918#section-3